# Appending Values from one list to another list based on line?

Tags: python, string, list, integer, append

I'm very new to python, and I want to concatenate each line in one list to another line in another list in python. I would like to put integers from a list in front of a each string in the string list. For example:

```
int = [1, 2, 3]
string = ['a', 'b', 'c']

final product: [1'a', 2'b', 3'c']
```

how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Take a look at zip

Comment: zip is the correct way to go about this, but it's worth noting that your output is not valid python. You either need `[(1,'a'),...` or ['1a',...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want string concatenation behavior, you can use `zip` in a list comprehension

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [str(i) + j for i, j in zip(nums, letters)]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this issue like this

```
final_product = []

for i in range(len(string)):
    final_product.append(zip(nums[i], string[i] ))
```